# How to get specific list from some list (tcl)

Tags: list, tcl

I'm beginner about tcl.
List are {A1 b} {A2 b} {A3 c} {A4 b}.

I want get specific sorted list. 
-> {A1 b} {A3 c}   => A1, A2, A4 are related with b. Among this, anything is okay.

I'd like to know how to solve about this.
Please Let me know.

Comment: We can't know about 2nd argument (b,c).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are looking for the -index and -unique options to `lsort`:

```
set list {{A1 b} {A2 b} {A3 c} {A4 b}}
puts [lsort -index 1 -unique $list]
```

Which results in: {A4 b} {A3 c}

Comment: I'll try it with your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another take: [groupby](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

```
proc groupby {list func} {
    set result [dict create]
    foreach element $list {
        set key [apply $func $element]
        dict lappend result $key $element
    }
    return $result
}
```

That takes a list and a function (see the [apply](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/apply.htm) command) and returns a dictionary whose keys are the function results and the values are the list of elements that had that result:

```
set list {{A1 b} {A2 b} {A3 c} {A4 b}}
set grouped [groupby $list {pair {lindex $pair end}}]
```

At this point, the `$grouped` dictionary has the value `b {{A1 b} {A2 b} {A4 b}} c {{A3 c}}`, so we can:

```
set wanted [lmap group [dict values $grouped] {lindex $group 0}] ;# => {{A1 b} {A3 c}}
```